# how to solve APP not installed on all android versions?

Tags: java, android

I don't have any unnecessary permissions in Mainfest when i try to install it on my phone it's give app not installed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
```

Comment: __Please__ at least give us your manifest.

Comment: Was it an unsigned build?

Can you try using a signed build?

Comment: unsigned  build uninstallable at all, signed build i can install it first time when i uninstall it and reinstall  it's show error APP not installed.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ? Have you deactivated `Instant Run` ?

Comment: Yes I use Android Studio, Instant Run is disable.